# how do I get the mouse-selected rows from JTable

Tags: java, user-interface, jtable

I need to get the value from table and display on another window, how do I know the mouse-selected row is in which index? should I use `MouseAdapter` instead of `ActionListener`? What does getSource return?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
jTable.getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {
    public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
        int sel = jTable.getSelectedRow();
    }
});
```

This will give you the selected row number.

Answer (score 1):

Actually I solved by using JTable methods, getSelectedRow() which returns the index of Row, and then I use getValueAt(rowNum,columnNum) to retrieve the value.

Comment: This works because `JTable` is itself a `ListSelectionListener`, as suggested in @vijay's [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24715114/230513).